# I cannot run Spring Boot App on the AWS EC2 server. Communication failure

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, deployment

I am trying to deploy the Spring Boot Application to *AWS EC2.*

The application is running fine on the local server. However, when I try to start it on the EC2 instance I get these errors:

- Log related:

```
2023-05-28 01:54:41,392 main ERROR Unable to create file /media/edoyou/HDD1/Kanan/k2s-project/k2sbeauty/logs/info.log java.io.IOException: Could not create directory /media/edoyou/HDD1/Kanan/k2s-project/k2sbeauty/logs
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.FileUtils.mkdir(FileUtils.java:128)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.FileUtils.makeParentDirs(FileUtils.java:141)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:734)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:718)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:144)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:100)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:217)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:135)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:62)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:124)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:1138)
...
...
```

- MySQL related:

```
2023-05-28 01:54:46.549 ERROR
            28130 --- [           main] c.z.h.p.HikariPool                       :
            HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:824) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:444) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:237) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:?]
```

The steps that I followed:

1. Created another *application-prod.properties* file (but I am not sure if it is correct, I will attach my original *.properties* file):

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://ec2-13-48-13-89.eu-north-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3306/k2salon
spring.datasource.username=EC2_DB_NAME
spring.datasource.password=EC2_DB_PASSWORD
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

2. I tried to build the app using: `mvn clean install`
3. Uploaded this **JAR** file to the EC2 instance and started it.

**application.properties**:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/k2salon?serverTimezone=UTC&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.username=${DB_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}

STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=${STRIPE_SECRET_KEY}

spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false

logging.config=classpath:log4j2-spring.xml
logging.file.path=${user.dir}/logs
logging.pattern.dateformat=mm

# SMPT details
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=${MY_GMAIL}
spring.mail.password=${GOOGLE_APP_PASSWORD}
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.jmx.enabled=false
spring.messages.fallback-to-system-locale=true
```

---

### Additional information: I am not experienced in app deployment. I am using Linux Ubuntu.

Comment: first error looks like your directory `/media/edoyou/HDD1/Kanan/k2s-project/k2sbeauty/logs` is not available on EC2 instance. you can use a more generic directory lile `var/logs` at `logging.file.path` in your application.properties file. second error related to DB looks like network or a security group issue. Have you added incoming security group rules to allow your EC2 instance access?

Comment: The directory `media/edoyou/HDD1/Kanan/k2s-project/k2sbeauty` is my application directory, in the local server. However these directories do not exist in the remote EC2 instance. So, it is normal to get these error. Should I upload whole the directory into the EC2 instance?

I even try to run `mysql --version`, it says "command not found". How do you use terminal for the remote EC2 instance? I think these are the first things that I need to understand in order to answer your questions :)

Comment: In order to resolve the 1st issue, you need to give an existing directory for your logging configuration, for ecample `logging.file.path=/var/logs` or you can create a new directory and set your directory there. For the second issue, you either need to create RDS for MySQL instance or, install MySQL on your EC2 instance. when you enter `mysql --version` it saying "command not found" means your EC2 instance doesn't have MySQL installed. A good practice would be to use a separate RDS instance for your DB instead of installing it on your EC2 instance for production use.

Comment: I am now trying to fix these issues. But I think the issue is when uploading the JAR file to the EC2 instance. Is this correct command to upload:```scp -i /home/edoyou/my-ssh-key.pem /media/edoyou/HDD1/Kanan/k2s-project/k2sbeauty/target/k2sbeauty-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ec2-user@ec2-15-222-1-81.ca-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com```? When I started deployment process first I used another command (I don't remember where I got it from), however I made slight changes in the .properties and wanted to upload the **JAR** again. However, I noticed that the JAR is not uploaded with above mentioned command.

Comment: You can easily troubleshoot if your JAr is uploaded or not using following method. Use `scp -i /home/edoyou/my-ssh-key.pem /media/edoyou/HDD1/Kanan/k2s-project/k2sbeauty/target/k2sbeauty-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ec2-user@ec2-15-222-1-81.ca-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com /home/ec2-user/` command when uploading your JAR file, then SSH into your EC2 instance and see if the JAR file is uploaded into directory `/home/ec2-user`

Comment: I fixed the issue, it is uploaded now. I modified log directory path in the .properties file to : `logging.file.path=/var/logs`, however, I get the exact same error. Plus, I checked that `/var/logs` directory exists when I run my terminal as the terminal for my EC2 remote instance. Am I stepping correctly?